# select event on an vis timeline item is no allowing to drag the same item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vis.js

I have a modal opening on selecting(onSelect) a vis timeline item, but I also want drag and drop functionality with items on the timeline. So, when i mousedown on the item to drag it, modal opens due to select event being fired - which is not allowing to drag the item.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is a correct solution, but you can try something like

```
var dateDown = 0;
var mouseTime = 100;//Time between mouse clicked and mouse dragged

//elem is your timeline or button
elem.onmousedown = function(e){
    dateDown = Date.now();
}

elem.onmouseup = function(e){
    if(Date.now() - dateDown > mouseTime){
        console.log("Mouse dragged");
    }else{
        console.log("Mouse clicked");
    }
}
```

I think there must be a better solution.